# CSS targeting <a> tags within <li>

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm trying to style a WooCommerce shop page and I'm getting really confused about the selectors I need.

In the image below, I want to remove the underline from the hyperlinks and make some other changes.

I've managed to target one `<a>` tag with

```
.woocommerce ul.products li a{
    outline: 1px solid red!important;
}
```

The price and the product title behave like hyperlinks, but I can't change the `text-decoration` to `none`. The title is in an `<h2>` and the price in a `<span>` but I can't make sense of how it all fits together

[image]

Any suggestions how to target all underlined text and remove the underlining please?

The markup is here:

```html
<ul>
<li class="product type-product post-1097 status-publish first instock product_cat-uncategorised has-post-thumbnail downloadable shipping-taxable purchasable product-type-simple">
   <a href="https://compucademy.co.uk/stg_2b77a/?product=test-product-1" class="woocommerce-LoopProduct-link woocommerce-loop-product__link">
      <img width="300" height="300" src="https://compucademy.co.uk/stg_2b77a/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/python-snake-3-wide-300x300.png" class="attachment-woocommerce_thumbnail size-woocommerce_thumbnail" alt="Python Tuition for Computer Science GCSE" srcset="https://compucademy.co.uk/stg_2b77a/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/python-snake-3-wide-300x300.png 300w, https://compucademy.co.uk/stg_2b77a/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/python-snake-3-wide-303x303.png 303w" sizes="(max-width: 300px) 100vw, 300px">
      <p></p>
      <h2 class="woocommerce-loop-product__title">Test Product 1</h2>
   </a>
   <p><a href="https://compucademy.co.uk/stg_2b77a/?product=test-product-1" class="woocommerce-LoopProduct-link woocommerce-loop-product__link"> <span class="price"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">£</span>0.00</span></span>
      </a><a href="/stg_2b77a/?page_id=1090&amp;add-to-cart=1097" data-quantity="1" class="button product_type_simple add_to_cart_button ajax_add_to_cart" data-product_id="1097" data-product_sku="" aria-label="Add “Test Product 1” to your basket" rel="nofollow">Get it now</a>
   </p>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: your img,title are wrapped within a link, price is also a link. :first-child, :last-child or any other pseudo class are also selectors. Have you tried one of them ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that underlining is being created using `text-decoration`, here's how you disabled that for all of the list items descendants. Check what actually is being used to create the underlining (it could as well be `border-bottom`, or even a pseudo element, or a gradient, or...).

```css
.products li * {
  text-decoration: none !important;
}
```

```html
<ul class="products">
<li class="product type-product post-1097 status-publish first instock product_cat-uncategorised has-post-thumbnail downloadable shipping-taxable purchasable product-type-simple">
   <a href="https://compucademy.co.uk/stg_2b77a/?product=test-product-1" class="woocommerce-LoopProduct-link woocommerce-loop-product__link">
      <img width="300" height="300" src="https://compucademy.co.uk/stg_2b77a/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/python-snake-3-wide-300x300.png" class="attachment-woocommerce_thumbnail size-woocommerce_thumbnail" alt="Python Tuition for Computer Science GCSE" srcset="https://compucademy.co.uk/stg_2b77a/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/python-snake-3-wide-300x300.png 300w, https://compucademy.co.uk/stg_2b77a/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/python-snake-3-wide-303x303.png 303w" sizes="(max-width: 300px) 100vw, 300px">
      <p></p>
      <h2 class="woocommerce-loop-product__title">Test Product 1</h2>
   </a>
   <p><a href="https://compucademy.co.uk/stg_2b77a/?product=test-product-1" class="woocommerce-LoopProduct-link woocommerce-loop-product__link"> <span class="price"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">£</span>0.00</span></span>
      </a><a href="/stg_2b77a/?page_id=1090&amp;add-to-cart=1097" data-quantity="1" class="button product_type_simple add_to_cart_button ajax_add_to_cart" data-product_id="1097" data-product_sku="" aria-label="Add “Test Product 1” to your basket" rel="nofollow">Get it now</a>
   </p>
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

its working here just use same and give following css targetting ur class name

```css
 ul li a{
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li class="product type-product post-1097 status-publish first instock product_cat-uncategorised has-post-thumbnail downloadable shipping-taxable purchasable product-type-simple">
   <a href="https://compucademy.co.uk/stg_2b77a/?product=test-product-1" class="woocommerce-LoopProduct-link woocommerce-loop-product__link">
      <img width="300" height="300" src="https://compucademy.co.uk/stg_2b77a/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/python-snake-3-wide-300x300.png" class="attachment-woocommerce_thumbnail size-woocommerce_thumbnail" alt="Python Tuition for Computer Science GCSE" srcset="https://compucademy.co.uk/stg_2b77a/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/python-snake-3-wide-300x300.png 300w, https://compucademy.co.uk/stg_2b77a/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/python-snake-3-wide-303x303.png 303w" sizes="(max-width: 300px) 100vw, 300px">
      <p></p>
      <h2 class="woocommerce-loop-product__title">Test Product 1</h2>
   </a>
   <p><a href="https://compucademy.co.uk/stg_2b77a/?product=test-product-1" class="woocommerce-LoopProduct-link woocommerce-loop-product__link">    <span class="price"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">£</span>0.00</span></span>
      </a><a href="/stg_2b77a/?page_id=1090&amp;add-to-cart=1097" data-quantity="1" class="button product_type_simple add_to_cart_button ajax_add_to_cart" data-product_id="1097" data-product_sku="" aria-label="Add “Test Product 1” to your basket" rel="nofollow">Get it now</a>
   </p>
</li>
</ul>
```